# Omit directory name when including header files in different folder than src

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, set-include-path

Suppose a folder structure in a C++ project with an `include` directory with header files,a `src` directory with `.cpp` files and the `makefile`. Lets assume `header.h` lives in `/include`,I want to be able to `#include` the header above without the `./include/` part. In my `makefile` I can add a `-I./include` flag,but my current problem is that (On VS Code) Clang complains about a `pp_file_not_found`,even though when compiling everything works fine. I am looking for either

- Supressing this error
- Somehow telling clang that `/include/` should be searched for headers

What's the workaround for using my `header.h` like `#include "header.h"` in a situation like this?

```
Structure 
 -include 
    -header.h
 -src
    main.cpp
    makefile
```

Header.h :

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <iostream>
void foo(int a) { std::cout << a << '\n'; }
#endif  // HEADER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h" // 'header.h' file not foundclang(pp_file_not_found)
int main() {
  foo(5);
  return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
all: main.o 
    clang++ main.o 

main.o: main.cpp ../include/header.h
    clang++ -c main.cpp -I../include
```

Comment: Since it's saying `pp_file_not_found`, I'm guessing it's _not_ using your `makefile`.

Comment: To the best of my recollection, VSCode uses `compile_commands.json` https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html  it definitely doesn't parse your makefile.

Comment: @drescherjm I have the extension installed,I havent really configured it though. I just have a simple makefile with a simple rule e.g. `g++ main.cpp -I./include/` which compiles the program fine. Can I configure the extension with clang to avoid this behavior?

Comment: I added the code and the structure in my last added for clarity

Comment: I can't help with the Makefile tools extension. It's supposed to generate and configure your c_cpp_properties.json to avoid the intellisense  warnings. [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) ***This extension provides IntelliSense configurations to the VS Code C/C++ Extension for Makefile projects. It also provides convenient commands to build, debug, and run your targets.***

Comment: Since I deleted a previous comment I put the link back in the latest comment for context.

Comment: @drescherjm Im on Arch so I dont have C/C++. I use the [Code-OSS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) and C/C++ extension isnt available,i guess this means that the Makefile Tools is useless?

Comment: I can't answer that. I hope someone with more experience will answer.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  If the header file is not found, then definitely the compile will fail, but you say "even though when compiling everything works fine".  Please show, via cut and paste with formatting, the exact make command you invoked, the exact compile line that make invoked, and the exact error message(s) you received.  Also, I don't understand your comment "I'm on Arch so I don't have C/C++"; do you mean Arch Linux?  All Linux systems have C/C++ compilers available for them, else they could not be built!

Comment: @MadScientist C/C++ extension for Vscode isnt available on Arch linux. I have g++ and clang++ ,thats not what i meant. Compiling the code via terminal with `g++ main.cpp -I../include` compiles just fine. But thats because I use the `-I` flag to include the header,when writing the code its annoying to deal with clang complaining about header not found. And i dont want to use `#include "../include/header.h"`,i want to use `#include "header.h"`

Comment: Please show the output I asked for.  I doubt it's really true that extensions are not available for Arch: most likely you just have to figure out how to install them.  But, that's irrelevant here: if your makefile is not working we need to see what it does because the info you've provided here looks correct... so there must be something you haven't shown us that's causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `compile_flags.txt` file, the clangd extension parses it:

```
-xc++
-I
./include
```

Or a `compile_flags.json` file, see clangd's description.

Comment: You may need to reopen your project in vscode after you add the `compile_flags.txt` file.